# How to pass javascript variable and save it in Rails database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, model

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to save a javascript variable from view to Rails Controller which is then saved to Model (database). The user answers a quiz/survey and is then taken to a results page. The results page has javascript that calculates the marks/results, and I want the marks to be saved to a database.

I looked around and notice the best solution is using AJAX from front-end and retrieve the data in the controller (back-end).

I have a single controller called quiz which has all my methods, and a model to store results called Score. The user's result should be saved after the result page is executed/visited.

Here is what I've done:

in quiz_controller.rb

```
def result
    @title = "Quiz Results"
end

def score
    @mark = Score.all
end

def mark
    quiz_name = params[:quiz]
    mark = params[:mark]
    @mark = Score.new(score_params)
    @mark.save
end

private 
    def score_params
        params.require(:score).permit(:quiz, :score)
    end
```

in result.html.erb

```
<script>

var mark = calcMark();

$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/mark?quiz=" + quiz + "&mark=" + mark,
  type: "POST",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
</script>
```

in 2019******_create_scores.rb

```
t.string "quiz", :limit => 50, :null => false
t.column "score", :decimal, :limit => 30, :null => false
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
```

in my routes.rb

```
get 'result' => 'quizs#result'
post 'result/mark' => 'quizs#mark'
```

Please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong. I still don't know if my route is correct and what the url of the ajax should be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the question? What's not working? What errors are you getting? There are a number of things that you are doing that are unconventional/peculiar. But, it is difficult to help unless you are more specific.

Comment: @DanzTim run rake routes, and what is score_params?  show us whole quiz_controller.rb.

Comment: @NeverBe my quiz_controller contains many other methods that represents each quiz, so I don't think I should show but I've modified my question above

Comment: @NeverBe here is the snippet when i run rake routes https://imgur.com/a/A7wEO6G

Comment: @DanzTim try url: "/result/mark?quiz=" + quiz + "&mark=" + mark

Comment: @jvillian The error that i'm getting is POST http://localhost:3000/mark?quiz=Sound&mark=5 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @NeverBe I tried that but now the error is 400 Bad request

Comment: what is final url? with all variables

Comment: @NeverBe http://localhost:3000/result/mark?quiz=Sound&mark=5

Comment: params.require(:score).permit(:quiz, :score)
 it means you must wrap params in score section. for json it is  {"score": {"quiz":"Sound", "mark":5}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax scripipt should be

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/result/mark",
    data: {"quiz": quiz, "score": mark},
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Rails action

```
def mark
    @mark = Score.create!(score_params)
end

private 
    def score_params
        params.permit(:quiz, :score)
    end
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be saving now, but now its got internal server error 500. Because ActiveRecord NOT NULL constraint failed. Here is the snip of rails console and schema.rb https://imgur.com/a/Lw1VJSV But I dont get why it throws error because created_at and updated_at is automatically assigned values?? But it says `VALUES (?, ?)`

Comment: in logs it says unpermitted params :quiz, :mark. Did you update score_params method? And quiz_name should be not empty, but you don't provide it or mixed with quiz column.

Comment: Hi, yes I did but I've changed the ajax data to `data: {quiz_name: name, score: result}` so its fine now. The status code is now 204 which is fine I guess. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To send post data you must set a data object for [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/result/mark",
    data: {"quiz": quiz, "mark": mark},
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Also same error 400 bad request, I tried adding `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json"` but that also didnt work